# PHP basename( __DIR__ ) is returning _DIR_ on some servers

Tags: php, filepath, dir

I'm hoping someone here knows the answer to this. I wrote a script that uses

`basename( __DIR__  )`

then uses an if file exist function.

On my server this works fine, however on other sever it actually returns the word `_DIR_` instead of the file path.

Did this change with a version of PHP or is there some other setting that makes it so this doesn’t work?

Lastly is there a better way to get the path of the file? Here is the whole line I’m using:

`define('NIFTY_CONSTANT', trailingslashit (WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/'. basename( __DIR__  ) ). '/lib/mdetect.php' );`

(yes I know it's a WordPress function but this is not a WordPress question it's a PHP one)

Comment: Please enable full error reporting. You'll probably see a [notice about an undefined `__DIR__` constant](http://3v4l.org/DKVRg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__DIR__` is introduced in PHP 5.3 . Double check your PHP version .

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 4):

If `__DIR__` constant doesn't work on server `A`, while works on server `B`, then a PHP Version is an issue (As mentioned by @Shivan).

You can simply test it by calling `phpinfo()` on both servers.

Here's a quick workaround for you:

```
// this should be at the top
if (!defined('__DIR__')) {
   define('__DIR__', dirname(__FILE__));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I accepted @shivan's answer and they responded first but your code is helpful as this is for code to be distributed throughout the internet.

Comment: This of course defines one global `__DIR__` constant which is the same for every file; that's not the same as the magic constant `__DIR__`.

Comment: What good is a "workaround" if it breaks your scripts? (This *will* break *something* if you use `__DIR__` in more than one file/directory.)

Comment: @Bandon If you need compatibility with PHP versions below 5.3, just use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__`.

Comment: @deceze Constants themselves "break" the scripts as they introduce another form of global state. A `__DIR__` should only be defined once at `bootstap` and should never be used within methods or functions. **The point here is:** I would only use `__DIR__` in the bootstrap and then pass its value as an argument, therefore it will never be used in more than one file.

Comment: That's not the same as the magic constant `__DIR__` then, which is different each time depending on where it's used. When using your "workaround", the script will behave very differently depending on whether it's running on 5.2- or 5.3+. `__DIR__` BTW is not "global state" at all (maybe that's what you're missing), it's in fact just a parser token that gets substituted with the current directory of the file that's being parsed. It's a reflection mechanism if you will, not global state.

Comment: Yes, `dirname(__FILE__) === __DIR__`, but you missed a point. If you use `__DIR__` throughout whole script, then your architecture is broken.

Comment: `function foo(){  __DIR__  }` is a global state, while `foo(__DIR__)` isn't

Comment: `__DIR__` is ***not global state***, because you do not need to define it beforehand and because it's always different each time it's used! What alternative do you propose to use instead of it to *get the directory of the current file*?!

Comment: Who is talking about how it works under the hood? Who cares? This can be any constant. In correct architecture a `__DIR__` must be dependency and therefore should always be passed as an argument.

Comment: @Bandon Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Apparently your problem is that you're missing that `__DIR__` is a ***magic*** "constant" whose value is *not* constant! So it *does* matter that we're talking about `__DIR__` and not any normal constant.

Comment: I didn't say you're wrong. You are correct when you say each time its different. But since `__DIR__` is a constant (**it doesn't really matter if its internal or used-defined**) and since its a dependency, then its a **concept** of highly-decoupled architecture. I would prefer `User::getAllThumbsById($username, $path)` over `User::getAllThumbsById($username)`, since all dependencies are obvious "under" data abstraction.

Comment: Where and how it's used is an entirely different matter. There are enough cases where it's perfectly cromulent to have a file introspect its own location. Say, you are including required files in a library: `require_once __DIR__ . '/module/foo.php'` or `$locales = file_get_content(__DIR__ . '/locales/iso-xyz.xml')`. Should you inject that? How? *Somewhere* you'll have to resolve that path using `__DIR__` or something equivalent, even if that's up the chain in the caller. `__DIR__` has a use and you can't replicate it with your own constants.

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://getcomposer.org Your approach works fine *in your own project*. How about small utility libraries that are meant to be distributed?